# Need help in mapping a Shapefile (.shp) using Folium and geopandas (python)

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I am trying to plot a circle on folium map using shapefile (.shp) format.
Below is the code that I have so far but no luck with it.

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m_ = folium.Map(location=[39.828259, -98.579528], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=4)
shp_map1 = gpd.read_file("3_4793.shp")
folium.GeoJson(data=shp_map1).add_to(m_)
m_
```

I tried below code:

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m_ = folium.Map(location=[39.828259, -98.579528], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=4)
shp_map1 = gpd.read_file("3_4793.shp")
folium.GeoJson(data=shp_map1).add_to(m_)
m_
```

And I expected to see something like below plot:

[image]

The shapefile (.shp) looks like this:

```
NOTAM_ID,TFR_TYPE,TFR_AREA,LOWER_ALT,LALT_TYPE,UPPER_ALT,UALT_TYPE,EFFECTIVE,geometry
0,3/4793,Section_91_137_a_2,Hazard Area1,0,MSL,10500,MSL,From 7/12/2023 to 7/12/2023 3:00 PM-5:00 AM daily  
,"POLYGON ((-0.0000000019704209 669553.7679050891, 1607.983023363161 669413.0874426533, 3167.108052057252 668995.320561381, 4630.001898210876 668313.161470158, 5952.215023057159 667387.3369069248, 7093.572772107495 666245.9779678509, 8019.395709634386 664923.764407957, 8701.553367455652 663460.8710683752, 9119.31892301608 661901.7471706085, 9259.998921907409 660293.7657637335, 9119.318924692287 658685.784356269, 8701.553370073661 657126.6604570029, 8019.395712061435 655663.7671156805, 7093.572773323522 654341.5535545852, 5952.215022628471 653200.1946153576, 4630.0018964685905 652274.3700530436, 3167.1080562726634 651592.210945962, 1607.9830236730784 651174.4440736491, -0.0000000019763304 651033.7636147812, -1607.9830236809835 651174.4440736491, -3167.1080562746392 651592.210945962, -4630.001896476494 652274.3700530436, -5952.215022630447 653200.1946153576, -7093.572773325498 654341.5535545852, -8019.395712061435 655663.7671156805, -8701.553370079584 657126.6604570029, -9119.318924696234 658685.784356269, -9259.998921909382 660293.7657637335, -9119.318923020026 661901.7471706085, -8701.553367457624 663460.8710683752, -8019.3957096363565 664923.764407957, -7093.572772111439 666245.9779678509, -5952.2150230611005 667387.3369069248, -4630.001898212847 668313.161470158, -3167.108052067105 668995.320561381, -1607.983023369072 669413.0874426533, -0.0000000019704209 669553.7679050891))"
```

Comment: I am trying to plot the polygon present within this shapefile. Can someone please help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Geodataframes have a `.to_json` method. Did you try using that instead of passing the raw dataframe?

Comment: @PaulH, No I did not try using that method. Is this something you can help generate an example for me? Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of examples at the geopandas website